# Permalinks settings

Tags: permalinks, redirect, urls, site-url

My homepage isn't working if I select the "*Post name*" setting. Everything else works fine.

When you visit [`www.clasificadosvallemedio.com`](http://www.clasificadosvallemedio.com/), it doesn't load. It should look like: [`www.clasificadosvallemedio.com/inicio`](http://www.clasificadosvallemedio.com/inico) which is my homepage.

The problem started after I changed the URL of my website (Settings > General > Site URL/URL). I was using a subdomain (ex: `clasificados.example.com`) and I changed it to `clasificadosvallemedio.com`. I didn't move any files, etc.

Comment: I see your website is loading fine at this moment, were you able to resolve your question? Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to visit either link successfully. I get a redirect loop error:

> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Changing the URL of your website in *Settings > General > Site URL* is not enough unfortunately. You will still have your post content with your sub domain URL (`clasificados.example.com`) causing your website to not load properly.

Once you've downloaded and imported your database to your localhost. Follow these steps:

1. Go and download [Interconnect IT's Database Search & Replace Script here](https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB/archive/master.zip)
2. Unzip the file and drop the folder where your WordPress is installed (the root) and rename the folder to **`replace`** ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9Ga5.png))
3. Navigate to the new folder you created in your browser (ex: `http://clasificadosvallemedio.com/replace`) and [you will see the search/replace tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbED1.png)
4. It should be pretty self-explanatory up to this point:

   - **`search for…`**: enter your old subdomain (`http://clasificados.example.com`)
   - **`replace with…`**: - enter your new domain (`http://clasificadosvallemedio.com`)

You can click the *dry run* button under *actions* to see what it will be replacing before you execute the script. Once you're done be sure to remove the `/replace/` folder.

Answer (score -1):

Paste your WordPress Address (URL) and your Site Address (URL). Plus give where you installed WP (maybe is this a problem, maybe not).

Cheers

Comment: While this is mainly where the URLs needs to be set to change, it's also advised to replace all of the old URLs on a database level to ensure all of the content is displaying correctly.